# QFileDialog cancelation

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

I'm new to QT. Currently in my project I implemented `QFileDialog`.

In my usecase : whenever user choose a text file, it executes `functionA`. However, I found that if I click cancel in the fileDialog, `functionA` will still be executed.

This is my code snipplet:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
                                                    "/home",
                                                 tr("Text File (*.txt"));

// I want something like following :

if(QFileDialog.isOkButtonClicked)
{
    // execute functionsA
}
```

I looked into `QFileDialog` documentation and nothing similiar.
Is it possible to achieve this or is there any other solution ? thanks.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName The doc is saying: "This is a convenience static function that returns an existing file selected by the user. If the user presses Cancel, it returns a null string."

Comment: Thanks for reply @AlexanderVX. I added `if(!fileName.isEmpty()&&fileName!="")` and it works. But i'm not sure is it what u connote ?

Comment: Yep. check for !filenName.isNull() will do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

thanks to AlexanderVX

the solution is simple :

```
if(!fileName.isEmpty()&& !fileName.isNull()){
// functionA
}
```